# filter feed titles with preg_match_all

Tags: php, filter, preg-match, preg-match-all

Help me with this please :)

I have this code which filters the feed titles. However this comes in a messy unordered list.

```
$countItem = 0;
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): {
  $checktitle = $item->get_permalink();
  $keyword_one = '/keyword1/';
  $keyword_two = '/keyword2/';
  if (preg_match_all($keyword_one, $checktitle, $matches) && preg_match_all($keyword_two, $checktitle, $matches)) {
     echo $item->get_title();
  }
}
endforeach; ?>
```

I want to echo the results in a div class as below, but I don't know how. It gives an error if I place the div after preg_match_all.

```
<div class="item">
     <a href="<?php echo $item->get_title(); ?>"</a>
     <p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
</div>
```

Not sure how to do, can you help me with that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`

```
$items = array_filter($feed->get_items(), function ($item) {
    return preg_match('/keyword1|keyword2/', $item->get_permalink());
});

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo '
<div class="item">
     <a href="' . $item->get_title() . '"</a>
     <p>' . $item->get_description() . '</p>
</div>';
}
```

Also, pay more attention when mixing between frontend and backend code. You have an extra `:` after the `foreach` loop: `foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): {`

Comment: Thanks for that. If I delete the ":" after the first foreach loop I get an unexpected endforeach error which is at the end of the code. If I leave it there the filtered items are showing but it takes forever to load page and sidebar is not displaying.

Comment: It depends on how many items you have of course... you might consider to implement a pagination and to try getting the items from the feed already filtered

Comment: Is there any way to create a searchform out of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't place html codes inside php. Close the php code using php close tag and then add html. Do as follows.

```
<?php
$countItem = 0;
foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): {
    $checktitle = $item->get_permalink();
    $keyword_one = '/keyword1/';
    $keyword_two = '/keyword2/';
    if (preg_match_all($keyword_one, $checktitle, $matches) && preg_match_all($keyword_two, $checktitle, $matches)) { 
    // Closing php tag..
    ?>
        <div class="item">
             <a href="<?php echo $item->get_title(); ?>"</a>
             <p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php // Opening php tag after adding html..
    }
}

?>
```